# TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `category`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have two schemas: Item and Category. I want to use Category in Items, how can i merge them? Here is the code:

Category:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true},
});

var categoryData = mongoose.model("categoryData", categorySchema);
module.exports = categoryData;
```

Item:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const categSchema = require("./category.js")

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    created: {type: Date, required: true, unique: true},
    category: [categSchema],
    quantity: {type: Number, required: true}
});

var itemData = mongoose.model("itemData", itemSchema);
module.exports = itemData;
```

And the error that i get is "TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `category`."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess it's happen 'cause you exported category model instead of schema. Change `module.exports = categoryData` to `module.exports = categorySchema`

Comment: [Additional docs about nested schemas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `module.exports` = `categoryData`

Do the following:

```
 module.exports = categorySchema.
```